# What is the difference between string[][] and string[,] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

The syntax is slightly different but what is the difference between them.

```
public static string[][] str1 = { new string[] { Total, "N2" }};
public static string[,] str2 = { { Total, "N2" } };
```

What are the guidelines for the use of each?

Comment: The first one is "jagged" - an array of references to arrays.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Basically, the difference is how the memory is allocated.
[,] notation will allocate all of the needed memory in one block, while [][] notation will allocate an array of pointers to arrays, where each array is allocated separately and not necessarily next to the others

Comment: Also check [Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2604h5s.aspx)

Comment: _"an array of **pointers** to arrays"_ - that depends on how its used- the elements might be [unitialised](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx).  Also, in c# the term "pointer" is not used commonly and should not be a synonym for _reference_.  _"[A jagged array is an array of arrays, and therefore its elements are reference types and are initialized to null](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)"_

Answer (score 0):

In the examples you quoted:

```
public static string[][] str1 = { new string[] { Total, "N2" }};
public static string[,] str2 = { { Total, "N2" } };
```

The first one is an array of arrays (**Jagged Array**). Each entry can point to an array of string.

The second one is a normal 2 dimensional array (**Multi Dimensional Array**).

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell , [,] is a 2d array allocated all at once, while [][] is an array of arrays thus memory allocation is gradual- the initialization syntax (as you pointed out) is different also.

One more important difference is that in a [][] type you can define each 'row' of a different size. which you can't do in [,] which is in a way a C# representation of a Matrix.